# When should I create a device driver?

Tags: drivers, embedded

I am working with an embedded system which has lots of code written by people, usually with more expertise than me.

Part of the embedded system kernel has a custom device driver based in I2C and V4L, and this driver is used by some of the applications that run in the system.

I guess (could be wrong?) all of these applications could be written and work without the custom driver without loss of important abstraction.
Also, the hardware associated with it does not change frequently, so the code reusability upon hardware changes is not a great advantage if compared to the complexity of work that it adds to the system.

After watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoYkHUnmpQo) (you guessed it: I'm kinda newbie with embedded device drivers) the only other advantage I can see in writing the device driver is exporting some functionalities to the userspace which, again, is not a great need in this project.

So, as far as I'm concerned the advantages of writing device drivers are:

- Exporting functionality to userspace
- Abstracting away frequent hardware changes
- Using frameworks to standardize node creation and device classes

None of these seems to matter to me.
Would I be making a mistake in re-writing the system/applications without the driver? Am I missing something here?
I also think about performance in execution, but is it that great?

Comment: This is essentially a software development question, so I think Stack Overflow would be a more appropriate place for it. But if you incorporate the functionality of the driver into the application and your hardware ever changes (and it will, because of manufacturing realities if nothing else), then you'll have to maintain two versions of your entire application: one for the old hardware version and another for the new. Dropping support for the old version means making your old customers unhappy.

Comment: Also, lumping everything together does not necessarily make things easier: it could also generate a monolith that is difficult to debug when (not if) something goes wrong. When the driver and app are separate, you can write a dedicated test app to verify driver functionality, and more easily plug the production app into a test harness to validate it. The driver should be consolidating the low-level hardware manipulations into conceptual operations that *make sense* for your application, so that you can rely on those operations without thinking about lower-level details.

Comment: tldr; keep the kernel code (drivers etc) as small and unchanging as possible.